# Approximation of bounded, differentiable function in $W^{1,p}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, approximation, dense-subspaces

Let's say we are on some bounded domain $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Under which conditions is $C^1(K)$ dense in $W^{1,p}(K)$? I would like to approximate a function in $W^{1,p}(K)$ by bounded $C^1(K)$ functions but am not sure whether or not the boundedness of the $C^1(K)$ function suffices in order to do so! I know that this often (for unbounded functions) is only possible under certain assumptions on the domain such as a Lipschitz boundary etc. - but this is not given here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dont your assumptions imply  $C^1(K) \subset W^{1,p}(K)$ ? then the question is trivial.

Comment: Well yes of course we have $C^1(K) \subset W^{1,p}(K)$ but I don't see why this would suffice to approximate any arbitrary $C^1(K)$ function by $W^{1,p}(K)$ functions (i.e. functions with no classical derivative)?

Comment: Ah now I see it, didn't think about it but the $W^(1,p)$ norm and the $C^1$ norm (that is either $||f||+||Df||$ or $\max\{||f||,||Df||\}$) should be equivalent!

Comment: Well I completely messed up! I've edited the post and what I actually want to show.  The problem is that I don't know any results regarding density of $C^1(K)\subset W^{1,p}(K)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Meyer-Serrin theorem from their famous $H=W$ paper: The set $C^\infty(K) \cap W^{m,p}(K)$ is dense in $W^{m,p}(K)$. No assumptions on $K$ needed. However, note that $C^\infty(K)$ functions might behave very badly close to the boundary, i.e., $u(x) = 1/x$ is in $C^\infty(0,1)$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meyers%E2%80%93Serrin_theorem

Comment: Thank you! And what if we additionally assume zero boundary values, i.e.: $C^1_0(K)\subset W^{1,p}_0(K)$? I don't think Meyer Serrin is needed then but simply the definition of $W^{1,p}_0(K)$ in order to approximate any function in $W^{1,p}_0(K)$ by functions in $C^1_0(K)$ in the $W^{1,p}$-norm, right?

Comment: yes, this is by definition, as $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: And the extra assumption of the boundedness of the approximating functions is no restriction as $C^\infty_0(K)$ functions are bounded anyway, right?
Thank you very much!